# Affine Schemes and Basic Open Sets

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, affine-schemes

Reading through a proof that a scheme is locally Noetherian if and only if every open, affine subscheme is induced by a Noetherian ring I came across the following which did not seem as obvious to me as it did to the person writing the proof.

Suppose $X=\mathrm{Spec} \ A$ is an affine scheme, and $U=\mathrm{Spec} \ B$ is an open, affine subscheme. Furthermore, if for some $f\in A$, $X_{f}\subset U$, letting $g$ be the image of $f$ in $B$ (via the restriction map), is it the case that $X_{f}=U_{g}$?

The restriction of $X$ to $U$ is isomorphic to $(\mathrm{Spec} \ B, \mathcal{O}_{\mathrm{Spec} \ B})$, but the associated homeomorphism could be quite complicated, so although $X_{f}$ will be mapped to an open set, I'm not sure why it would necessarily be $U_{g}$. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is true.  Note that $X_f$ is just the set of points $p\in X$ such that the image of $f$ in the stalk $\mathcal{O}_{X,p}$ is not in the maximal ideal.  On the other hand, $U_g$ is the set of points $p\in U$ such that the image of $g$ in the stalk $\mathcal{O}_{U,p}$ is not in the maximal ideal.  But these two conditions are identical: the stalks $\mathcal{O}_{X,p}$ and $\mathcal{O}_{U,p}$ are the same, and the image of $f$ in $\mathcal{O}_{X,p}$ is the same as the image of $g$ in $\mathcal{O}_{U,p}$ since $g$ is the restriction of $f$.

(Note that none of this has anything to do with affine schemes in particular.  The same argument would apply if $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ was any locally ringed space, with $f\in \mathcal{O}_X(X)$ some global section and $g$ the restriction of $f$ to $\mathcal{O}_X(U)$.)

Comment: Am I right in thinking then that this relies, in an essential way, on a scheme morphism taking the maximal ideal in a stalk to the corresponding maximal ideal in the corresponding stalk? Is there are a way to prove this result without referencing stalks?

Comment: Well, not really, because we aren't talking about arbitrary scheme morphisms: we're only talking about open subschemes, for which the stalks are trivially isomorphic (and so in particular send the maximal ideal to the maximal ideal).

Comment: If you want to avoid mentioning stalks, you can just cover $U$ by subsets that are distinguished open subsets of both $\operatorname{Spec} A$ and $\operatorname{Spec} B$.  The intersection of $X_f$ with each such set is just the distinguished open subset defined by the restriction of $f$, and similarly for $U_g$.  But the restriction of $f$ and the restriction of $g$ are the same, and so the intersections of $X_f$ and $U_g$ with each of our sets covering $U$ is the same.

Comment: Or, you can say that $X_f$ is the union of all open subsets of $X$ on which the restriction of $f$ is invertible.  This definition obviously gives the same answer when you apply it to $U_g$.

Comment: Really, how you say it just depends on your definition/what you know about $X_f$.  In all cases, the point is that the definition just involves properties of restrictions of $f$, and the restrictions of $f$ are the same as the restrictions of $g$.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments. The thing I'm still stuck on is this: there is a homeomorphism between $\mathrm{Spec} \ A$ restricted to $U$, and $\mathrm{Spec} \ B$, everything would be ok if $X_{f}$ was mapped to $U_{g}$, but surely this homeomorphism could be totally crazy. It feels like all the proofs I've read assume this homeomorphism is induced by the restriction map from $A$ to $B$.

Comment: That's what it means for $U$ to be an open subscheme of $X$...there's not just a homeomorphism, but the sheaf of rings is also the same.

Comment: I don't really know what you think it means for the homeomorphism to be "induced by the restriction map".  The restriction map is by definition our map of rings dual to the map of affine schemes $\operatorname{Spec} B\to\operatorname{Spec} A$, i.e. the induced map on global functions.

Comment: I know there's also a sheaf of rings, but to identify sets in the topological spaces the sheaf isn't that much help. By "induced by the restriction map" I just meant the map from $B$ to $A$ induced a map between the corresponding affine schemes. Having thought about the whole thing, your original answer makes a lot of sense to me now, I'm just still at the stage where I need to think about the explicit isomorphism (of locally ringed spaces), and it seems like the proof does require that the maximal ideals in the stalks are exchanged (i.e. we don't just have an isomorphism of ringed spaces).

Comment: An isomorphism of ringed spaces is the same thing as an isomorphism of locally ringed spaces.  The morphisms only differ when you look at morphisms that are not isomorphisms...

Comment: Sure, but an isomorphism of locally ringed spaces presupposes that the stalks are local rings, whereas this isn't the case for general isomorphisms of ringed spaces right?

Comment: OK, but in this case the stalks happen to be local rings.  I'm not sure what your point is.